# Is there a music player that can play a 150,000 song library?

Tags: music

I have a very large collection of music. Over the years I have slowly put it all on my computer as .mp3 files. The entire library is about 360 GB and consists of about 150K separate tracks. My entire life, I have had a dream of putting all of my music on one portable device that I could listen to, like an iPod, and shuffle through all 150k songs without difficulty.

Unfortunately, I have yet to find such a device. I have tried many many different things, the most recent being the iBasso DX90, which had the capacity to hold all of the songs, but was unusable do to the massive amounts of lag.

My question is this: Does anyone know if there is a device that can do what I'm asking? If not, what are some of my other options to carry my entire library around without using multiple devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using a phone ? Recent ones can achieve more than 512GB with onboard memory and/or micro SD card. Otherwise, I've seen the Archos 48 Internet tablet, a 4.8" tablet with 500GB, but probably slow (well, archos..)

Comment: @Jules R I asked some phone "experts" at the store if a phone would be able to work, but they all gave a resounding no, saying that that memory is intended for pictures and apps, not that much music.

Comment: I'm inclined to not believe such "experts", see [here](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-sd-card-support-for-offline-google-play-music/) among others. Since I'm guessing you have a phone anyways, that's my recommendation. If, however, you'd like a dedicated player, replacing the spinning drive in an iPod Classic with an SD card is an option–though, given how expensive iPod Classics are now, not a cheap one. What phone are you using at the moment?

Comment: @JMY1000 I was doubtful myself, but not willing to upgrade my phone to test it out. I have a Huawei XT2 right now, which is pretty low end, but I will ask some family members if I can test it out on their better devices.

Comment: Okay. If you do end up looking at a new phone, we can help with that too; there are plenty of budget offerings with SD cards.

Comment: Cannot compare with my 5GB, but seems like there isn't any problem. That's less than 3 times less, but still a lot, so should work https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/5ckcvo/music_app_with_smart_shuffle/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE3X9lmDZTs

Answer (score 2):

Alright, there we go. Phones now have quite big storage capabilities, going up to hundreds of GBs, and even more with µSD cards. They are also more and more powerful, so a recent phone (like your Moto G6) should be totaly capable of going through your library.

Just for curiosity, how much time does it take to launch shuffle mode with 150K songs ?